# MySQL: Join table iteself. Unknow column

Tags: mysql, inner-join, database-table

To go Mad!!!!

On Access works and on MySQL don't want. And I take the trick on a post here.

Here the query:

```
SELECT A.B_ID,
       B.CNT_B,
       B.MAX_PRICE,
       B.SUM_AB,
       B.SUM_C_AB,
       B.UNIQUE_B,
       B.Costi,
       B.COUNTDOWN,
       A.AUCT_ID
FROM MONITOR AS A
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT B_ID,
          COUNT(B_ID) AS CNT_B,
          MAX(PREZZO_ATTUALE) AS MAX_PRICE,
          SUM(TOT_PUNT_AB) AS SUM_AB,
          SUM(TOT_CAMBI_AB) AS SUM_C_AB,
          (CNT_B-SUM_AB) AS UNIQUE_B,
          (0.035*3*CNT_B+MAX_PRICE) AS COSTI,
          45-SUM(CONT_PROVV_AB) AS COUNTDOWN
   FROM MONITOR
   WHERE AUCT_ID = '123456789'
   GROUP BY B_ID) AS B
  ON A.B_ID= B.B_ID
WHERE A.AUCT_ID = '123456789'
ORDER BY B.MAX_PRICE DESC,
         B.CNT_B DESC
```

shows

> ERROR: [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.5.33-31.1-log]Unknown column
>   'CNT_B' in 'field list'

If I leave CNT_B, it tells me MAX_PRICE and so on.

I'm sure. It's a INNER JOIN malediction!

[Here the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f10e3/1) with the error

---

**SOLUTION**

I can't use ALIAS value inside same sub-query.

So the new VALID query is:

```
   SELECT A.B_ID,
           B.CNT_B,
           B.MAX_PRICE,
           B.SUM_AB,
           B.SUM_C_AB,
           B.UNIQUE_B,
           B.Costi,
           B.COUNTDOWN,
           A.AUCT_ID
    FROM MONITOR AS A
    INNER JOIN
      (SELECT B_ID,
              COUNT(B_ID) AS CNT_B,
              MAX(PREZZO_ATTUALE) AS MAX_PRICE,
              SUM(TOT_PUNT_AB) AS SUM_AB,
              SUM(TOT_CAMBI_AB) AS SUM_C_AB,
              (COUNT(B_ID)-SUM(TOT_PUNT_AB)) AS UNIQUE_B,
              (0.035*3*COUNT(B_ID)+MAX(PREZZO_ATTUALE)) AS COSTI,
              45-SUM(CONT_PROVV_AB) AS COUNTDOWN
       FROM MONITOR
       WHERE AUCT_ID = '123456789'
       GROUP BY B_ID) AS B
      ON A.B_ID= B.B_ID
    WHERE A.AUCT_ID = '123456789'
    ORDER BY B.MAX_PRICE DESC,
             B.CNT_B DESC
```

and the [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f10e3/8)

Thanks

Oscar

Comment: Where does `C.MAX_PRICE` come from?

Comment: Results from a `SHOW CREATE TABLE MONITOR` would be nice, but I notice that your query references a `C.MAX_PRICE` when no `C` table is specified, so that should be fixed. Doh, sniped.

Comment: I edited post with correction and the SQLfiddle for the error example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move up from Sub-query to the main the following:

```
 (CNT_B-SUM_AB) AS UNIQUE_B,
 (0.035*3*CNT_B+MAX_PRICE) AS COSTI,
```

Because you are trying to call an **Alias** from a `Computed Aggregate` function by itself.

So that you will have this:

```
SELECT A.B_ID,
   B.CNT_B,
   B.MAX_PRICE,
   B.SUM_AB,
   B.SUM_C_AB,
   B.CNT_B-B.SUM_AB AS UNIQUE_B,
   (0.035*3*B.CNT_B+B.MAX_PRICE) AS COSTI,
   B.COUNTDOWN,
   A.AUCT_ID
FROM MONITOR A
INNER JOIN
 (SELECT B_ID,
      COUNT(B_ID) AS CNT_B,
      MAX(PREZZO_ATTUALE) AS MAX_PRICE,
      SUM(TOT_PUNT_AB) AS SUM_AB,
      SUM(TOT_CAMBI_AB) AS SUM_C_AB,
      45-SUM(CONT_PROVV_AB) AS COUNTDOWN
FROM MONITOR
WHERE AUCT_ID = '3453015'
GROUP BY B_ID) B
ON A.B_ID= B.B_ID
WHERE A.AUCT_ID = '3453015'
ORDER BY B.MAX_PRICE DESC,
     B.CNT_B DESC
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f10e3/17)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, which doesn't reference a `C` table:

```
SELECT A.B_ID,
       B.CNT_B,
       B.MAX_PRICE,
       B.SUM_AB,
       B.SUM_C_AB,
       B.UNIQUE_B,
       B.Costi,
       B.COUNTDOWN,
       A.AUCT_ID
FROM MONITOR AS A
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT B_ID,
          COUNT(B_ID) AS CNT_B,
          MAX(PREZZO_ATTUALE) AS MAX_PRICE,
          SUM(TOT_PUNT_AB) AS SUM_AB,
          SUM(TOT_CAMBI_AB) AS SUM_C_AB,
          (CNT_B-SUM_AB) AS UNIQUE_B,
          (0.035*3*CNT_B+MAX_PRICE) AS COSTI,
          45-SUM(CONT_PROVV_AB) AS COUNTDOWN
   FROM MONITOR
   WHERE AUCT_ID = '123456789'
   GROUP BY B_ID) AS B
  ON A.B_ID= B.B_ID
WHERE A.AUCT_ID = '123456789'
ORDER BY B.MAX_PRICE DESC,
         B.CNT_B DESC
```

Comment: It's the same. I made and SqlFiddle.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "it's the same". Is there still an error? That fiddle isn't showing an error with my suggested change.

Comment: Sorry zanlok, but if I copy/paste your query it gives the same error. Probably I'm missing something. Anyway, I solved by making tests for each subquery. If you look here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f10e3/1 you can see the same error that gave me, that I solved it avoiding the use of the values ​​of aliases in the same subquery. In fact if you see your query, for example the "(0.035*3*CNT_B+MAX_PRICE) AS COSTI" [istead of "(0.035*3*COUNT(B_ID)+MAX(PREZZO_ATTUALE) AS COSTI"] tries to use the value of CNT_B and MAX_PRICE made in the same query. And this "it's the same" of my first query.